# Skype integration issue

Tags: iphone, ios, skype, skype4com, skype4py

I'm new in iOS development. But anyway now I can: post private messages to my friends on Facebook and Twitter.

Is there any way to post message to my skype contact's?

Does skype provide any API for iOS to post message to skype contact's?

Is there any way to gain skype contacts information (email, phone number), so to be able to post email/SMS to skype contact directly?

What is the best way to post data to my skype contacts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No currently there is no public API is provided for iOS.**

You can check their documents [skypekit](http://developer.skype.com/public/skypekit) and [api reference](http://developer.skype.com/desktop-api-reference#Reference) for more details.

You can use [Skype Uri](https://developer.skype.com/skype-uri) for communicating with skype from your APP.

Comment: I'm readying your information now. And information in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569125/how-to-integrate-skype-feature-in-my-native-app. I will read and answer you in 20 minutes

Comment: @Wolvorin: with Pleasure :)

Comment: @PaulGalavic: Ok dude :) If you found anything useful please edit my answer or add your own answer :)

Comment: @Midhun MP, I looked at all your references and googled around, but I din't find the wat how I can gain the list of skype contacts al least. I event found out, that I can't open skype to write a message (only call, actually I can write a message, but this functionality offen doesn't work). So I think , that I can't send private message with skype and I can't gain contact list. If I'm not right, please, give a code

Answer (score 0):

Try look at this repositories

[Projects on Objective-C with Skype support](https://github.com/search?q=skype&p=1&ref=searchbar&type=Repositories&l=Objective-C)

Comment: but those are for MAC dude not for iOS :)

Answer (score 0):

Sevabot Skype bot provides a HTTP interface for sending Skype messages:

https://github.com/opensourcehacker/sevabot

(Disclaimer: I am author of the project)

However, using this solution means that you need to have a Skype client running on your server.